# include cmake headerfile boost.hpp with cmake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I like to add the `boost/operators.hpp` with cmake

From CMake's FindBoost Documentation:

```
 find_package(Boost 1.36.0)
 if(Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  add_executable(foo foo.cc)
 endif()
```

So I added

```
find_package(Boost 1.60.0)
if (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    add_library(core ${core_SRCS})
    add_executable(app main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(app core)

endif ()
```

Output from message:

```
-- Boost version: 1.60.0
-- BOOST_ROOT=~/Projects/ClionProjects/.repo/boost_1_60_0
-- Boost_DIR=Boost_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- Boost_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/dornathal/Projects/ClionProjects/.repo/boost_1_60_0
```

However it builds (I can run the program and tests), but as soon as I try to include `#include<boost/operators.hpp>` it won't find it in the test project.

I actually extended one class by the `boost::operators<T>` and strangely my IDE (CLion) lets me jump to that sourcefile.

Comment: `operations.hpp` is not the same as `operators.hpp`.

Comment: okay fixed my posting of course I used operators.hpp when including

Comment: There's no "of course" about it. We can't read your real code.

Comment: I think it is a bit verbose to post a complete class if the compilation fails on an include statement. Everything that could fix that shoukd be in the cmake build process. At least I thought so, but I could add the class if needed.

Comment: What is the contents of the `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable (e.g. if you print it using `message()`)? And, in the generated project, is there an incorrect path to Boost specified, or is there none at all?

Comment: The Boost_INCLUDE_DIR contains the path to the extracted boost archive I downloaded. However, Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `include_directories` CMake command adds include directories for the current directory and its subdirectories. Since you get the error in the test project and use `include_directories` in the main project, I guess the problem is that you have separate directories for these, for example:

```
src/
  CMakeLists.txt - include_directories used here
test/
  test.cc - no effect on this file
```

If this is the case you can either move `include_directories` up to their common parent directory or use [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) that can propagate the public `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property.

You can also see the commands passed to your compiler by adding `VERBOSE=1` to your make command:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

This shows what include directories are passed to the compiler via the `-I...` option among other things.